# bash trap won't ignore signal

Tags: bash, signals, rsync, bash-trap

Please consider this bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap '' INT

echo sleep:  
sleep 5

echo rsync:  
rsync -a /usr/lib /var/tmp
```

Trying to interrupt sleep with ctrl-c fails, as expected. But rsync is interruptible (the order of sleep & rsync doesn't matter)? Any ideas are welcome!

Edit:
Found a difference: rsync itself starts 2 child procs (client/server, which produce the 2 error msgs, i assume), and these seem not to inherit the 'ignorance' of its parent. Must dive into bash sources and find out how trap is working...

Comment: `rsync` is setting its own signal handler, overriding yours?

Comment: Here is a link to a very similar problem. Looking there might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624947/bash-not-trapping-interrupts-during-rsync-subshell-exec-statements

Comment: thanks for the link, but i had read that one yet. but the solution to that problem didn't help me - or i haven't unterstand it the right way :/ @tripleee: then the trap is useless? why does the ctrl-c go 'through' the shell?

Comment: The shell does (more or less): `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)`.  Any child process (such as `rsync`) inherits ignored signal handling.  However, if `rsync` carelessly and unconditionally does `signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler)`, that undoes the shell's attempt to protect it from interrupts.  That's why the books always advise you test: `if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN) signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);`.  All this is at the C code level, of course.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your detailed explanation. Now it's clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `rsync` with `--no-detach` as advised in the SO question [`bash` not trapping interrupts during `rsync` subshell/exec statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624947/bash-not-trapping-interrupts-during-rsync-subshell-exec-statements)?

Comment: @davak: Thanks for the tip, but that option is for rsync running as daemon only.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty clear from experimentation that `rsync` behaves like other tools such as `ping` and do not inherit signals from the calling Bash parent.

So you have to get a little creative with this and do something like the following:

```
$ cat rsync.bash
#!/bin/sh

 set -m
 trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
 rsync -avz LargeTestFile.500M root@host.mydom.com:/tmp/. &
 wait

 echo FIN
```

Now when I run it:

```
$ ./rsync.bash
X11 forwarding request failed
building file list ... done
LargeTestFile.500M
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
sent 509984 bytes  received 42 bytes  92732.00 bytes/sec
total size is 524288000  speedup is 1027.96
FIN
```

And we can see the file did fully transfer:

```
$ ll -h | grep Large
-rw-------. 1  501 games 500M Jul  9 21:44 LargeTestFile.500M
```

#### How it works

The trick here is we're telling Bash via `set -m` to disable job controls on any background jobs within it. We're then backgrounding the `rsync` and then running a `wait` command which will wait on the last run command, `rsync`, until it's complete.

We then guard the entire script with the `trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT`.

#### References

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/360713
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1539283
- [Delay termination of script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450127/delay-termination-of-script)