# How to prevent subprocesses from receiving CTRL+C / Control+C / SIGINT

Tags: scala, jvm, subprocess, signals, sigint

My Scala script creates subprocesses like this:

```
val exitValue = Process(Seq("bash", "-c", command), dir) ! processLogger
```

with command being e.g. `"mvn clean package"` or for testing of this issue `"sleep 20"`.

For some reason my script has to intercept SIGINT, because the user might have meant “copy” instead of “stop it” (really happens from time to time). I achieved this by adding a signal handler like this:

```
Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), this)

override def handle(sig: Signal)
{
    log.warn("Ignoring SIGINT (Ctrl+C). Press [Esc] instead.")
}
```

However when a subprocess is running this does not work, because CTRL+C makes it stop. What can I do so that the subprocess ignores SIGINT? I found a solution for Python:
[Python: How to prevent subprocesses from receiving CTRL-C / Control-C / SIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045771/python-how-to-prevent-subprocesses-from-receiving-ctrl-c-control-c-sigint/5050521#5050521)
Is there something similar for Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you launch `bash`, you may use `trap` built-in command to ignore signals in a subprocess.

Just prepend `trap '' SIGINT;` (with the semicolon) to the `command`:

```
Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "trap '' SIGINT;" + command))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I even thought of calling `python` to achieve this 

Comment: Actually you might want to take a look at this neat trick to run the process in different process group so that a user CTRL-C is not dispatched to your sub-process(es): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51256203/926540