# parent shell not getting SIGINT when child has a handler

Tags: c, linux, signals

When you press Ctrl-C, foreground processes receive SIGINT:

```
$ bash -c 'sleep 100; echo program died'
^C
$ echo $?
130
```

However, if a program installs a SIGINT handler, parent program doesn't receive the signal. Why?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sig_int(int sig_num)
{
    exit(1);
}

static struct sigaction sigact = { .sa_handler=sig_int };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sigaction(SIGINT,&sigact,NULL);
    sleep(100);
    return 0;
}
```

bash didn't die:

```
$ bash -c './a.out; echo program died'
^Cprogram died
```

Related to [Bash not trapping interrupts during rsync/subshell exec statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624947/bash-not-trapping-interrupts-during-rsync-subshell-exec-statements) , but all answers there are workarounds.

Comment: I think that this is related to this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149741/why-is-sigint-not-propagated-to-child-process-when-sent-to-its-parent-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The shell ignore SIGINT if not sent directly from the terminal

This long [post](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) explain what is happening in details. Here I'll try to summarise the most important concepts and propose a working solution.

---

It turns out that the shell is programmed to ignore the **SIGINT** if it is not directly sent from the terminal (by hitting `CTRL-C`). If a subprocess intercepts it then it must exit by explicitly killing itself with **SIGINT**, quoting the post:

> "If you don't catch SIGINT, the system automatically does the right
>   thing for you: Your program exits and the calling program gets the
>   right "I-exited-on-SIGINT" status after waiting for your exit.
>
> But once you catch SIGINT, you have to take care of the proper way to
>   exit after whatever cleanup you do in your SIGINT handler.
>
> Decide whether the SIGINT is used for exit/abort purposes and hence a
>   shellscript calling this program should discontinue. This is hopefully
>   obvious. If you just need to do some cleanup on SIGINT, but then exit
>   immediately, the answer is "yes".
>
> If so, you have to tell the calling program about it by exiting with
>   the "I-exited-on-SIGINT" status.
>
> There is no other way of doing this than to kill yourself with a
>   SIGINT signal. Do it by resetting the SIGINT handler to SIG_DFL, then
>   send yourself the signal.
>
> ```
> void sigint_handler(int sig)
> {
>   [do some cleanup]
>   signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
>   kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
> }
> ```

---

**SIGINT Handler**

Here is a working version of the handler that intercepts the signal and correctly kill itself (and thus it doesn't print 'program died'). 
OTOH, If you send a different signal the handler run the `exit` function and you will see again 'program died' printed on the screen.

```
void sig_int(int sig_num)
{
    if (sig_num == SIGINT) {
        printf("received SIGINT\n");
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
    } else {
        exit(1);
    }
}

static struct sigaction sigact = { .sa_handler=sig_int };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sigaction(SIGINT,&sigact,NULL);
    printf("go to sleep\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("awaken\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. Bash is being too smart again and ignores SIGINT, if child didn't die of SIGINT